# How to receive a notification message from LOCAL SERVER such as WAMP to android devices?

Tags: android, push-notification, localhost, wamp, mqtt

How to receive a notification message from LOCAL SERVER such as WAMP to android devices?

I dont wanna use C2DM or GCM because there is no internet connection. so i have to use local server. but how to push a notification from local server such as WAMP server to an android device? all devices are in LAN Network...
I heard something about MQTT but i m not sure is it work for local server or not

i want to send a notification from Device1 and it receive from server(Local) and server(Local) Push it that notification to the another Android Device2

Comment: +1 for , i worked with gcm notification but not on local server notifcation

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562316/basic-steps-for-using-mqtt-in-android?rq=1