# Android push notification using MQTT instead of using FCM

Tags: android, firebase, mqtt

I have an Android application developing in Java and using Firebase Database. This application will send the notification to the users when uploaded something to the database. Therefore, I want to ask whether can the application send push notification using MQTT instead of using Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562316/basic-steps-for-using-mqtt-in-android

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, I want to ask whether can the application send push notification using MQTT instead of using Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)?

You can use whatever you want. There's no requirement to stick Google service for this.